# Memory corrupted in block while using free function in C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have written a code to write some information to every xml files in a directory. To check, if the file is an XML I did strncpy to get the format. The result of strncpy is put into a char pointer. After the task I free that result pointer. But when I try to free it, I get error saying:

fatal: file1.c:1449: memory corrupted after block (0xad41d2, 5 bytes)
    prev block: file2.c:137 (0xa4d5a2, 320 bytes)
    next block: file1.c:1449 (0xbe6ee2, 5 bytes)

If I comment the free statement, I see warning and everything runs fine.

Here is my code:

```
while ((in_file = readdir(FD)))
    {
        if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, "."))
            continue;
        if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, ".."))
            continue;

        char *output=(char*)xmalloc(sizeof(char)*5);
        /* Open directory entry file for common operation */
        strncpy(output, in_file->d_name+strlen(in_file->d_name)-5,5);
        output[5]='\0';

        /* open only xml files */
        if(strcmp(output,"_.xml")==0)
        {

            entry_file = fopen(in_file->d_name, "a");
            if (entry_file == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error : Failed to open entry file - %s\n", strerror(errno));
                fclose(entry_file);

                return;
            }
            fprintf(entry_file,"</component>\n");
            fclose(entry_file);
        }
    //  free(output); /* FIXME This line gives me error*/

    }
```

Could anyone help me on what is wrong here and why I am getting error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an invalid access:

```
output[5]='\0';
```

You allocated space for 5 characters here

```
char *output=(char*)xmalloc(sizeof(char)*5);
```

but the valid indices that can be used are 0 - 4.

---

Also, why allocate?  Just declare a char array of 5.

```
char output[5];
```

or better yet, make that an array of 6 chars since you need the terminating null byte.

```
char output[6];
```

By dynamically allocating memory, you opened yourself up for a memory leak here:

```
if (entry_file == NULL)
{
   printf("Error : Failed to open entry file - %s\n", strerror(errno));
   fclose(entry_file);
   return;  // forgot to free() the memory
}
```

and in any other place where a return may occur (either in your current code or future coding changes).

Comment: Yes! I can. Why I didnt think about that :< array is a better choice :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider these two lines:

```
char *output=(char*)xmalloc(sizeof(char)*5);
```

You've allocated `output` as five characters, `output[0]` through `output[4]`

```
output[5]='\0';
```

`output[5]` is outside this range. Behavior is undefined.

Comment: If I do not put that null, then I get garbage values after 5 characters in output array. Like this : _.xml$@#*& . However, I misunderstood the article. This is the error. Thank you.

Comment: @Luniam, if you need 5 real characters, you'd have to allocate 6 to have space for the terminating `0` byte.